# HashSet ExceptWith not working with complex types

Tags: c#, hashset

G'day,
I am trying to find the difference between data that I have on an SQL server and data I have stored Locally. I store the local and SQL data in a 2 separate HashSets.

Now I can confirm there is only 1 point of difference between the hashsets, but when I run `SQLHashSet.ExceptWith(LocalHashSet)` it gives me the complete Hashset instead of just that one extra record.

I am using this custom type:

```
class Client : IEquatable<Client>
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public override int GetHashCode() 
    {
        return StringComparer.InvariantCulture.GetHashCode(this.ID);
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Client);
    }

    public bool Equals(Client obj)
    {
        return obj != null && StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Equals(ID, obj.ID);
    }
}
```

Is my understanding of how ExceptWith works wrong or do I need to devise my own way to compare the lists?

Comment: Are you certain the `SQLHashSet` and the `LocalHashSet` don't have different values? Could one not be trimmed? Are you checking the `SQLHashSet` or the `LocalHashSet` for values after running `SQLHashSet.ExceptWith(LocalHashSet)`?

Comment: On the first run the application creates a copy of the data from the SQL server to a local file. I manually add a single record and run the program again. The program detects there is 1 more record but still returns the full HashSet.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with your code: `var SQLHashSet = new HashSet<Client> { new Client { ID = "Hello" }, new Client { ID = "World" } }; var LocalHashSet = new HashSet<Client> { new Client { ID = "World" } }; SQLHashSet.ExceptWith(LocalHashSet);` correctly reduces SQLHashSet to the "Hello" entry. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ah you were correct, when the data is retrieved off the SQL server again it isn't trimmed, would you like to put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work with how you've implemented `IEquatable<Client>` and overriden `GetHashCode`, so it's more likely that the issue is actually with your data. You should ensure that the data is being trimmed before you load it into your `HashSet`, as `"SomeValue"` will not match `"SomeValue   "`.